# Repcached issue

Tags: apache

Anyone using repcached?

Basically, I am experimenting with it in order to use it for storing sessions there, while providing failover with its buildin replication

Basically, I have 2 nodes running centos 5.4. The replication works fine wi\hen testing it and running some benchmarks with ab.

However, I am doing the below test.

I am having the 2 nodes started and replicating and start an ab test. While the benchmark is running, I take down one of the node, just to check the fail over.

At that point apache's error log starts printing

```
[Fri Oct 15 21:39:02 2010] [notice] child pid 2941 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

It seems that some requests fail during the fail over

Anyone encountered such behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this is caused by php's client memcache client.

Installing version 3.0.3 from pecl did the trick

The error appears with versions 3.0.4 and 3.0.5

I hope it will save people time